# How to select nth child with css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Given the following HTML and CSS I want to highlight the second element in the list using a `nth-child` pseudo class. How would I change the below to accomplish this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/DHKj5/

**HTML**

```
<div id="topdiv">
    <div class="middlediv">
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.topdiv > div:nth-child(n+2) {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4N4Py/)</kbd>

```
#topdiv .middlediv > div:nth-child(2) {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

You need to use `#` for id and `.` for class

Just to explain `n+2` will select all the siblings following the 2nd element. Also `>` will select only the immediate children of the matching selector.

Comment: It should `color: red`, not `font-color: red`.

Answer (score 2):

You select IDs via `#` and classes via `.`. With `nth-child()` you can simply pass the index (zero based) to it to select the element you need, in your case 2

```
#topdiv .middlediv > div:nth-child(2) {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DHKj5/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
#topdiv > .middlediv div:nth-child(2) {
color: olive;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DHKj5/4/

`.topdiv > div:nth-child(n+2)`

Doesn't work because the descendant divs you are trying to style are not children, but instead *grandchildren* of `#topdiv` and you also used a `.` on the root div instead of `#` (which is meant to target an elements ID)

More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo